# (self-answered) How would I detect collision on a canvas between a ball and a paddle?

Tags: javascript, pong

```js
let paddle1 = {
    x: 0,
    y: canvas.height / 2 - PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2,
};

let paddle2 = {
    x: canvas.width - PADDLE_WIDTH,
    y: canvas.height / 2 - PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2,
};

let ball = {
    x: canvas.width / 2,
    y: canvas.height / 2,
    leftorright: Math.round(Math.random()),
    upordown: Math.round(Math.random()),
};
```

is the paddles & ball and the part I really need help with detecting if the ball hits the paddle. What I was trying to do is check the X and the Y to see if it was between the top of the paddle and the bottom, but it wouldn't work.

```
function checkCollision() {
  if (ball.x <= 45) {
    // I tried to check the x and the y here but couldn't figure out how
    ball.leftorright = 1
  }
  if (ball.x >= canvas.width - 65) {
    ball.leftorright = 0
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly won't work?

Comment: What didn't work is that I checked the Y to see if it was between the top of the paddle and the bottom by using a for loop but it wouldn't work. @DraškoKokić

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find collision between two objects (say `paddle` and `ball`), make sure the x position of the right hitbox edge of `ball` is to the right of the left edge of `paddle` (`ball.x + BALL_WIDTH > paddle.x`), its left hitbox edge is to the left of `paddle`'s right edge (`ball.x < paddle.x + PADDLE_WIDTH`), the bottom of `ball` is below the upper edge of paddle (`ball.y + BALL_HEIGHT > paddle.y`), and finally the top of `ball` is above the lower edge of the paddle (`ball.y < paddle.y + PADDLE_HEIGHT`).

I can't figure out which side of the board the paddle is on, so remove whichever one is a given (say if it's on the left, we know for sure it can't collide below the upper edge in a useful manner, and it would be better just to let it clip through and lose)

Comment: paddle1 is on the left paddle2 is on the right

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, the collision detection can ignore `ball.x + BALL_WIDTH > paddle1.x` and `ball.x < paddle2.x + PADDLE_WIDTH`.

Answer (score -1):

You should check if `ball.x` equals the `x` edge of each paddle, and then check if `ball.y` is between `paddle.y` and `paddle.y + PADDLE_HEIGHT`

```
function checkCollision(){
  // PADDLE 1
  if (ball.x === paddle1.x + PADDLE_WIDTH && (ball.y >= paddle1.y && ball.y <= paddle1.y + PADDLE_HEIGHT )) {
    // HIT PADDLE 1
    ball.leftorright = 1
  }

  // PADDLE 2
  if (ball.x === paddle2.x && (ball.y >= paddle2.y && ball.y <= paddle2.y + PADDLE_HEIGHT )) {
    // HIT PADDLE 2
    ball.leftorright = 0
  }
}
```

To check for goals:

```
if (ball.x > canvas.width) {
  // PLAYER 1 SCORES
}

if (ball.x < 0) {
  // PLAYER 2 SCORES
}
```

Comment: huh, that won't work

Comment: @Leo why won't it work?

Comment: i don't know, it just doesn't do anything and YES: I ran the function